# fixed header element till it reached top of other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a webpage where I want a featured image that background scrolls with the speed of browser scroll. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Uncite/6stm31z4/)

`$(window).scroll(function () {
$("#featured-image").css("background-position", "50%" + ($(this).scrollTop()) + "px");
});`

The problem is that now the background scrolls, but element stays empty and I see white space. I want that element to decrease in size. I thought about many solutions, but then I thought about the idea to make the bottom of header element to scroll down till it passes the featured-image element and connects with top of #content element. The problem is that the height of header and height of featured-image are variable. Could someone point me to the right solution for this problem?

I need to keep the featured-image element without height because it now works perfectly on responsive design.

here is my jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/Uncite/6stm31z4/

Comment: @AGE: https://jsfiddle.net/Uncite/6stm31z4/

Comment: I think you should play with your implementation more, by that I mean a couple of things: why do you desire your functionality (scroll) to affect the featured image alone, and given how your html is formatted, why not playing to make it function more like (for example) this: http://bigomaha.co/ where all the core elements scroll to the speed of the browser and your header is top fixed? You have your reasons but I hope you see my point in the application of your scrollable function tied to your HTML elements

Comment: I need this because this will be a mobile website in which I don't want a sticky header. I want header to be in normal document flow.